# Querying a table with a composite primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with composite primary keys. This is a cross reference table and looks like this

```
Table 
ID    Relationship             ID2
1     Spouse                   10
2     Employee                 20
2     Former Employee          20
3     Former Employee          30
4     Child                    40
```

I am trying to write a query where ID2 matches, you have both employee and former employee for same ID

```
ID    Relationship             ID2
2     Employee                 20
2     Former Employee          20
```

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: It might be best to simply select all records for that ID and pivot them in the application. Especially since the number of columns you need will vary for each ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, id2) AS cnt
        FROM    mytable t
        WHERE   relationship IN ('Employee', 'Former Employee')
        ) q
WHERE   cnt = 2
```

Cross-platform version:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, id2
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   relationship IN ('Employee', 'Former Employee')
        GROUP BY
                id, id2
        HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) q
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.id = q.id
        AND t.id2 = q.id2
        AND t.relationship IN ('Employee', 'Former Employee')
```

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi!! Its Oracle and I tried your second query.  It pulls up the data I want but also pulls up the ID which has employee or former employee with a different ID2

Comment: @Cindy: could you please post you table definition?

Comment: @Cindy: sure, thanks :) The first query, however, would be more efficient in Oracle.

Comment: @Quassnoi - how do I do that? this is my first time on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Cindy: there is a number of upvotes under my answer's title. Click on the up arrow above the number to upvote it, and on the outlined check mark under the number to accept it.

Comment: @Quassnoi- got it but i cant upvote as it says I need 15 reputation which I dont have currently:(

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where ID2 in (
   select ID2 from table where count(ID2) > 1) t
order by ID2
```

Comment: this wont work as I am looking to filter it to just employees and former employees